# put_item in DDB Global Table uploads to wrong region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, amazon-dynamodb-global

I created a Lambda function in the `eu-west-3` region to put some data from one table to another.

I use **boto3** and I'm trying to put items from one DDB table in `eu-west-3` region to another Global Table in `eu-west-3` region.

However, I can see that the Global Table in `eu-west-3` has size - 0 bytes and the Global Table in `us-west-2` has the size of 9kb. Does it mean that the items are currently in `us-west-2` instead of `eu-west-3?`

I also understand that those should be replicated across all regions, but I'd still like to write to the correct region.

GlobalTable has replicas in 3 regions `['eu-west-3', 'us-west-2', 'ap-southeast-1']`

Is it possible to change it and actually put items to the `eu-west-3?`

```py
existing_region = 'eu-west-3'
global_table = boto3.resource('dynamodb',
    region_name=existing_region
).Table('GlobalTableName')

print("Updating table with data...")

with global_table.batch_writer() as batch:
    for item in table_items:
        batch.put_item(Item=item)
```

Comment: It doesn’t make sense when you say “I'm trying to put items from one DDB table in eu-west-3 region to another Global Table in eu-west-3 region” because you can’t replicate within the same region.

Comment: thank you for your response. I'm working with two different tables not related to each other that are in one region.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing us only part of the code that's writing to the table, but I suspect, your problem is another one anyway:

> However, I can see that the Global Table in eu-west-3 has size - 0 bytes and the Global Table in us-west-2 has the size of 9kb.

The size of a DynamoDB table you can see is not computed in real-time and is updated roughly every six hours.

[image: Screenshot showing that counts are updated every six hours]

Check the items in the table, most likely they are where they should be, otherwise we need to see more code.